# Xampp mysql not starting

Tags: mysql, xampp, phpmyadmin

Today when I am trying to start my MYSQL from Xampp, its not starting and throwing below error in logs. No other instance is running on my machine for MYSQL.

[Attached logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYZIT.png)

XAMPP error display:
[image: XAmpp error display]

[Actual Error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdQBI.png)

Please help I need to fix in very urgent.

Comment: There is no any error in "Attached logs".

Comment: Sorry, I have added Xampp control panel error display logs. Please have a look and suggest solution.

Comment: If you do have text based logs please post them as text. Did you try to repair the table?

Comment: I have reinstalled entire xampp used my backup queries to setup DB again. No i was not able to connect mysql as it throws cannot connect to localhost so i was not able to repair as well. I am eager to know solution as this happened to me 3rd time in 1 month.